# How to write join queries on TimescaleDB hypertables that don't scan chunks outside a given time range

Tags: sql, postgresql, timescaledb

Consider the following set of tables:

```
create table devices(
    id integer,
    primary key(id)
);

create table metrics(
                        ts timestamp,
                        id integer,
                        power double precision,
                        primary key (ts, id)
);
select create_hypertable('metrics', 'ts', chunk_time_interval := interval '1 days');

create table forecast(
                         ts timestamp,
                         id integer,
                         forecast_power double precision,
                         primary key (ts, id)
);
select create_hypertable('forecast', 'ts', chunk_time_interval := interval '1 days');

create table default_forecast(
                                 ts timestamp,
                                 default_forecast_power double precision,
                                 primary key(ts)
);
select create_hypertable('default_forecast', 'ts', chunk_time_interval := interval '1 days');
```

and this view:

```
create or replace view vw_forecast as
(
select d.id,
       df.ts,
       coalesce(f.forecast_power, df.default_forecast_power) as forecast_power
from devices d
         join default_forecast df on true
         left join forecast f on df.ts = f.ts and f.id = d.id
    );
```

adding some data:

```
insert into metrics(ts, id, power)
select times.ts,
       d.id,
       5
from devices d,
     generate_series('2000-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp, '2001-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp,
                     '5 minutes'::interval) as times(ts);

insert into forecast(ts, id, forecast_power)
select times.ts,
       d.id,
       6
from devices d,
     generate_series('2000-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp, '2001-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp,
                     '2 hour'::interval) as times(ts);

insert into default_forecast(ts, default_forecast_power)
select times.ts,
       7
from generate_series('2000-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp, '2001-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp,
                     '1 hour'::interval) as times(ts);
```

and executing this query:

```
explain(analyze, format json)
select *
from metrics m
         join vw_forecast f on f.id = m.id and f.ts = time_bucket('1 hour', m.ts)
where m.ts between '2000-01-10 00:00:00' and '2000-01-11 00:00:00';
```

I observe that the query plan results in a sequential scan on both the `forecast` and `default_forecast` tables.  I realize that I could expose the timestamp columns from both the `forecast` and the `default_forecast` tables in `vw_forecast` and additionally add constraints in the where clause of my query over these timestamp columns which would eliminate the sequential scan.  However, I would like to use this view in multiple contexts, and not burden consumers of the view who join against it with adding multiple constraints in order to get reasonable performance.  Is there a way to accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to add some extra where clause limiting the vw_forecast table too?

Some new fragment like:

```sql
and f.ts between '2000-01-10 00:00:00' and '2000-01-11 00:00:00';
```

Looking the full view with explain:

```sql
explain(analyze)
select *
from metrics m
         join vw_forecast f on f.id = m.id and f.ts = time_bucket('1 hour', m.ts)
where m.ts between '2000-01-10 00:00:00' and '2000-01-11 00:00:00' 
and f.ts between '2000-01-10 00:00:00' and '2000-01-11 00:00:00';
...
│ Planning Time: 79.190 ms                                                                                                                                                                               │
│ Execution Time: 273.094 ms
```

Comparing without the extra where clause:

```sql
explain(analyze)
select *
from metrics m
         join vw_forecast f on f.id = m.id and f.ts = time_bucket('1 hour', m.ts)
where m.ts between '2000-01-10 00:00:00' and '2000-01-11 00:00:00';
...
│ Planning Time: 207.309 ms                                                                                                                                                                              │
│ Execution Time: 414.093 ms
```

Note that the where clause is on your query not attached to your view directly.

Comment: it also looks like it might be quite useful to have an index on id, ts on these tables. Some of them also don't look like they need to be hypertables.

Comment: On my system, running with postgres 13 on docker (the timescale/timescaledb:2.5.1-pg13 image), using exactly the DDL I posted and running explain(analyze) both with and without the additional constraint you suggest results in many sequential scans of all the chunks.  E.g.,  `->  Seq Scan on _hyper_2_724_chunk f_357  (cost=0.00..1.60 rows=60 width=20) (actual time=0.023..0.598 rows=60 loops=1)`.  These scans are what I would like to avoid.

Comment: @davidk, do you mean an additional index to what I get with `primary key (ts, id)` on  the `metrics` and `forecast` tables?

Comment: Probably your primary key should be on (id, ts) rather than (ts, id), the search on (id, ts) is usually much more efficient.

Comment: (also, if you actually only have 60 rows in chunks your chunks are way too small and you won't gain anything from an index scan because 60 rows can fit on one or two pages anyway, so do look into your chunk sizing, should probably have at least 1-2 million rows per chunk and that index and then you'll start seeing index scans etc)